# Is dissociation/detachment associated with gamma wave?

Tags: cognitive-neuroscience, pain, brain-waves

In [this answer](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/a/15733/12937), it is said that pain signals can be numbed by dissociating through detachment (a psychological effect). On the other hand, in the article "[The Brain of Buddha](https://christofkoch.files.wordpress.com/2013/12/cr-brain-buddha-13.pdf)" by Christof Koch, it seems that a high intensity of [gamma wave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_wave) can also relief the pain (a neurotic effect).

So does dissociation/detachment associates with gamma wave? The Kock's paper doesn't mention anything about the dissociation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do certain individuals, like Quang Duc, develop the ability to remain calm when enduring significant nociceptive pain?](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/questions/15730/how-do-certain-individuals-like-quang-duc-develop-the-ability-to-remain-calm-w)

Comment: I feel you answered this at https://psychology.stackexchange.com/a/19829

Comment: The Kock's paper doesn't mention anything about the dissociation.

Comment: Maybe not, @Ooker, but couple your answer with mine, and meditation involves "clearing your mind", removing your conscious awareness from fears, and present troubles, therefore you are dissociating from everything for the time being in order to achieve the meditative state required.